# cannot find -latomic clang++.exe

Tags: android, android-ndk, tesseract, tess-two

I am trying to use `tess-two` to `OCR` text in image using android by following [this tutorial](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/840623/Android-Character-Recognition).
After I installed `android-ndk` and add folder path to environment variables, I got error when I tried to use `ndk-build`.

> C:/Users/Yasser/AppData/Roaming/IDM/android-ndk-r10c/toolchains/aarch64-linux-android-4.9/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-android/4.9/../../../../aarch64-linux-android/bin\ld.exe: cannot find -latomic
>   clang++.exe: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
>   make.exe: *** [obj/local/arm64-v8a/libtess.so] Error 1

I don't understand what is the problem.

Comment: your ndk version is too old...

Comment: ndk 19b is out currently. NDK version 19b is out atm. The CodeProject link is old. Find the new NDK version [here](https://developer.android.com/ndk/downloads)